# Loop invariant (java)

Tags: java, loops, loop-invariant

I have the following code to reverse the digits in an integer:

```
public class integerReversal {
    public static int reverseNum(int number){
        int reversed = 0;
        int remainder;
        //{I:  ; B: number > 0}
        while (number > 0){
            remainder = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
            reversed = reversed * 10 + remainder; 
        }
        //{I: ; !B: number == 0}
    return reversed;
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){ 
        System.out.println(reverseNum(1262015 ));
    }
}
```

My professor tasked us with writing this code and also said to write the loop invariant and loop condition.  I understand the loop condition here, I'm just unsure what I should be looking at for the invariant.  I realize that it is some condition that will be true at the beginning and end of the while loop, for every iteration, I just do not see what it would be here.  Tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems your professor wants you to use a different loop such as for, the comment above the loop gives a hint of for loop.

Comment: The comment was my own; my professor specified that we should be using a while-loop to write this.  What about the comment indicates that it should be a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

In your case reversed >=0 is your loop invariant, as it will always remain true, whether you are breaking loop or not.

Comment: That was my initial guess but it seemed a bit trivial.  Is that usually the case?

Comment: A loop invariant is some condition that holds true for every iteration of the loop. In your loop the predicate reversed >= 0 is a loop invariant, because it's true always.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question or let me know if you have any more doubts. Thanks.

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya I'm afraid you don't really understand loop invariants

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for commenting on my knowledge, but I believe let's not waste our time and energy in this as I am well aware of my knowledge, and try to focus on our answers.

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya fair point. I was trying to say that I felt your answer was misleading but I agree I didn't express that point well. I added my own answer that I believe is a better expression of the invariant. Looks like the questioner has lost interest in any case!

Answer (score 0):

A loop invariant is a constant expression involving values that are designed to change each iteration.

In your case in each iteration `number` is the number without the rightmost digit and `reversed` is the number you have built from the remainders in previous iterations. So I believe the answer is that in every iteration the following expression remains constant:

```
number * 10 + reverseNum(reversed)
```

In other words, at any time you can get the original number back by reversing your current solution and adding 10 * the current number.

This sort of invariant is very useful in testing your algorithm - some coders will regularly include an `assert` statement to test these types of invariants.

There can be several invariants - in your case there are a number of inequalities that remain true.